# Is there any greater meaning behind the inclusion of religious elements in Disney's Encanto?

Tags: encanto

**Premise**

The majority of Disney/Pixar movies contain little or no overt religious content — in the form of symbols, imagery, or direct references — to real-world religions.

Where such content has been included, it has largely taken the form of non-denominational spot references to cultural artifacts (*The Little Mermaid*) or vague Eastern-themed content (For example, a non-specified ancestral temple in *Turning Red* or the Hindu-themed content in *Raya and the Last Dragon*).

Where an acknowledgement has been made of an afterlife, it is typically left open as to whether it has any direct relationship with a real-world religious equivalent (*The Great Beyond*).

Where real-world cultures are shown, the religious aspects of those cultures are often not featured (*Luca*), or are featured in a way that is heavily modified to make them ceremonial *(The Emperor's New Groove*), or are anthropomorphic and character-based (*Moana*, *Hercules*, *Coco*).

Modern Western religions rarely feature.

In *Encanto*, they specifically showed a church and priest from a recognizable denomination on several occasions, referenced them in dialog, and one character had a traditional church wedding, which was depicted in part on screen.

The only animated feature to contain more overt and identifiable content was *The Hunchback of Notre Dame*.

**Question**

Has any of the promotional material made mention of this inclusion as having a "specific meaning" or being for "a specific reason", or have any of the people involved in its production remarked on it (For example, during interviews or panel events at conventions)?

For example, to make it more relatable to audiences in specific countries

Conversely, has there been anything from Disney/Pixar/those behind the movie, saying that it has no specific meaning? For example, that it was simply a recreation of a scene from their reference material on Colombia?

Comment: Because it takes place in Columbia which is culturally very Catholic?

Comment: @DeeV has this been officially or unofficially confirmed in any verifiable source?

Comment: I don't know but that seems like the most likely reason. I believe there were references to Christianity in Coco as well though probably not as overtly as showing a church with a priest.

Comment: The wedding and funeral scenes in Up (2009, post-Disney) were in an American church with a priest right next to the main characters, and the coronation scene in Frozen was in a [chapel, conducted by a bishop](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Arendelle_Chapel).There's even a  [Pope Car in Cars](https://pixarcars.fandom.com/wiki/Pope_Pinion_IV) . That's three just off the top of my head.  I feel like the pattern is "they include it when it's relevant to the plot",

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8, I'll give you UP, but the bishop in Frozen was pretty much a fudge so that it was not readily identifiable as any particular denomination and the ceremony was secular. Cars was parody so I'm not sure that counts.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox, Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought that you were saying that Disney\Pixar chose to include religious elements in the movie because it was set in a country that practiced that religion. I didn't understand that these were separate statements, and was asking for some kind of official source to confirm that they chose to include religious elements due to the location.

Comment: How is "the bishop in Frozen pretty much a fudge"? The link above shows the chapel was based on a specific church in the Norwegian village of Balestrand, with identifiable influences from the Lutheran Church of Norway. And it's a *coronation*, in a fictional fantasy kingdom, it didn't need to be religious or resemble a real-world denomination at all, but they made it so anyway. Clearly not "avoided religious imagery or language".

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8, well, you said it, it's a secular ceremony in a fantasy kingdom with no identifiable denominational symbols in a 10 year old move. So it's not an overt or identifiable religious symbol in a recent movie.

Comment: @Todd wilcox, for the purposes of this question considerer these terms to be interchangeable as the movie ends up the same either way.

Answer (score 8):

In an interview, Jared Bush, one of the writers/directors said:

> we got to go down to Colombia, and we spent a couple weeks with families in tiny, small towns where we met some more really great friends. It's really been a five-year research trip for us. The research doesn't end. And the fact that we have this amazing group of people that have really taught us so much — we've learned so much over these five years — and it hasn't ended. At any point in the process they can raise their hands and say, “Did you think about this?” Or, “That's not exactly right.” Or, “Maybe you could add this.”

<sup>[source](https://news.disney.com/encanto-directors-interview)</sup>

Religion is an important part of every culture. To think that they could have studied Colombian family life for years and **not** decided to include the religious aspects of Colombian culture is harder to believe.

In case you're not convinced about religion in real-life Colombia, here's a source for that: https://culturalatlas.sbs.com.au/colombian-culture/colombian-culture-religion

> Religion – specifically Catholicism – is deeply infused in the public life of Colombia. This is visible in the language. For example, one might hear the following phrases on a daily basis: “Si dios quiere” (God willing), “Dios te bendiga” (God bless you) and “Gracias a dios” (thank God).

Comment: Great primary source directly from one of people involved.  Upvoted. It'd argue though they did something similar with Luca, Tangled and Brave, but left the religious aspects of the local people out, and only included a very stylized version of local beliefs in Moana, most of the movies set in the US or Canada have almost nothing. I understand why they'd leave it out, it's more a question of what makes Encanto different to include it.

Comment: @AaarghZombies it’s not clear what kind of answer you’re looking for. They wanted to show Columbian family life. Religion is important in Columbian family life. So they showed religion. What’s missing from that chain of reasoning that would satisfy you?

Comment: a source that states exactly that would be perfect.

Comment: I upvoted your original answer, and I'm not disputing that they included religion because it is an important part of life in Columbia. I'm simply asking if there is a source where they directly state that they included religious elements for this exact reason. Your source doesn't mention religion, and I'm looking for something that actually mentions religious elements in relation to the story. Either to say explicitly that it was for a particular reason, or to say that there isn't any greater meaning to it. If no source exists then that too would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @AaarghZombies Ok thank you, now I understand